# Flutter connect MySQL Database to Socket for real time

Tags: mysql, flutter, sockets, dart

I have been researching for quite some time and have not figured a way to connect a MySQL Database using Socket in Flutter to get that real time fetch and push the data, more specifically a Table from the Database. For Example I am using a Database named `appDatabase` with couple of tables inside storing the data, and more specifically I want the real time to happen on the table named `chatMessages`, I was wondering if someone knows how to connect this MySQL Database to Socket to get the real time Chat. Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried so far and what did not work? Did you get error, for example?

Comment: I have used this `final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');
` as stated on the flutter.dev website, I have also watched some other tutorials but most tutorials are referred to this flutter.dev website about websockets, but there are no tutorials nor explanations out there explaining how to connect the socket to a specific MySQL Database and a table inside

Comment: You can't use WebSockets to communicate with MySQL. You need to use the MySQL protocol over plain TCP/IP sockets. Normally you would use a library for this. I don't know Flutter so I don't know if a library is available.